# Debugging and understanding code with possible dynamic function creation

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following python package, [python-searchengine](https://github.com/qoda/python-searchengine).
However running the shell command `python -m searchengine.main '"Python Search Engine" GitHub -bitbucket'` throws the error

```
AttributeError: 'SearchEngine' object has no attribute 'search'
```

which I think is correct as the [class SearchEngine](https://github.com/qoda/python-searchengine/blob/536a02e7cc094debca5432c58116f12e36c55ea7/searchengine/main.py#L6)

```
class SearchEngine(object):
    """

    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

has no property called `search`
I would have called that code buggy, but the project seems to have some forks and watches, which makes me rethink about my understanding of python. I am quite new to python, so it could be that I am missing out some vital clue, something like the function is getting created dynamically !

Can someone explain, how this function [searchengine](https://github.com/qoda/python-searchengine/blob/536a02e7cc094debca5432c58116f12e36c55ea7/searchengine/main.py#L15)

```
def searchengine(query, *args, **kwargs):
    search_engine = SearchEngine(*args, **kwargs)
    search_engine.search(query)
```

supposed to work!

Comment: It doesn’t look like the project was left in a working state when it was abandoned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the readme there is header:
**NB: UNDER DEVELOPMENT**

Also this repository is 9 years old. The code is incomplete and there are only two commits to this file. That would suggest project is just unfinished and this portion of code doesn't yet work (and won't ever work). So you should try looking for an alternative.